# Script search path

Tags: php, command-line

I use some command line PHP scripts. The author for them does not use shebang line. I keep them in `/opt/scripts` directory.

Currently if I want to run them outside of that directory I must use the full path, example

```
php /opt/scripts/foo.php
```

I would prefer to use

```
php foo.php
```

regardless of the current directory. Can I perhaps modify `php.ini` or some other trick to allow this?

Comment: Why don't you try `../../foo.php` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would naturally be handled by the includes_path directive, but won't be taken into consideration with the initial file from CLI; includes used within the file will utilize includes_path.

See:

```
[root@host ~]# php -v
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2010 16:55:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
[root@host ~]# php -i | grep include_path
include_path => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
[root@host ~]# ls /usr/lib/php
Archive  Console  HTML  Net  OS  PEAR  PEAR.php  PEAR5.php  Structures  System.php  XML  build  data  doc  pearcmd.php  peclcmd.php  test
[root@host ~]# php PEAR.php
Could not open input file: PEAR.php
```

One alternative is to use write a shell script (called phpinc.sh let's say) that reads in the INI file, parses it for include_path, and calls `php ${INCLUDE_PATH_PREFIX}$1`. You'll have to add that path to a php.ini file ...for example:

```
#!/bin/sh    
INCLUDE_PATH_PREFIX=grep -Ei '^include_path.*:([^ ]+)' /usr/local/lib/php.ini | grep -oEi ":[^:]+" | grep -oEi "[^:\"]+" | tail -1
php ${INCLUDE_PATH_PREFIX}$1 -c $2
```

Usage:
phpinc.sh file.php /path/to/custom/php.ini

I don't use grep that extensively in CLI (usually have PCRE API or wrapper), so there might be a better way of narrowing down the last include path.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your include path in your php.ini with adding '/opt/scripts/' directory path.